# Epoch Date Conversion to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, epoch

Good Day,

I have a question. What type of epoch date's are these and how would I convert them into a SQL Server `datetime` format.

```
37564691530
37564704499
37564708633
37564721033
37564743361
37564746236
```

I have googled for 2 days and cant find anything except this formula which gives me an arithmetic overflow message when i try to convert it.

```
select 
    DATEADD(ss, 37564691530 - 3600 * 5, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102))
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

13 digit epoch represent total **milliseconds** 10 digit epoch represent total **seconds**. You have first one - milliseconds.
And sql DateAdd function accept second parameter(Increment) as Integer. You try to pass a bigint value. Thats why throw Arithmetic overflow error.

try this

```
DECLARE @MS BIGINT
SET @MS = 37564746236
select DATEADD(SECOND, @MS / 1000, '1970-01-01')
```

Comment: But, please, [just type out `SECOND`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx)...

Comment: Hi Musthaan, thank you for your help. I have tried your function and it works, the only thing that i cant work out is for the value of 37564746236 to actually equal a date somewhere between the range of 2015-04-26 00:00:00 and 2015-04-26 23:59:59. the epoch date is supposed to be 1990-01-01 but it still outputs a date of '1971-03-11 18:39:06.000' Any ideas? this is really driving me crazy :)