# SQL Server - I need to see correct date/time and not a number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table in a SQL Server 2005 database that I would like to get a report on. If I simply use "*Script Table as*" in SQL Server Management Studio, I can get the information I need but the column I am interested in, which should contain a date and time, just contains `558262380`.

Are there some SQL commands I could add to the bottom of the "script" to convert that number to something more meaningful?

Below is a screenshot - it's the "**Delayed Until**" data I need to display as a correct date and time.

[image]

Comment: what is the data type of that column?

Comment: you can use DATEADD function, DATEADD(ss, columnName, '19700101')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Epoch Date Conversion to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016815/epoch-date-conversion-to-sql-server)

Comment: A date such as 558262380 looks to me like an epoch date (which, translating 558262380, results in Thur Sept 10, 1987, 8:53 am)

Comment: David Makogon - I should have said in the original post - that 558262380 represents 09/09/2017 08:53 am

Comment: user380887 - the format is "int"

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick: choosing the wrong datatype](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). The first subheading is "Using CHAR / VARCHAR / INT for date / time values"

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this date is calculated as elapsed seconds starting from **01/01/2000**.

You should be able to get the corresponding datetime using `DATEADD()` as follows:

```
select DATEADD(SECOND, 558262380 , '2000-01-01')
```

This is the output of this command:

[image]

Your original query should become:

```
SELECT  [Trader_Number]
       ,[Start_Trading_Hours] 
       ,[End_Trading_Hours] 
       ,[Inactivity_Period] 
       ,DATEADD(SECOND, [Delayed_Until], '2000-01-01') as [Delayed_Until] 
FROM [EMDC_1].[dbo].[Autologoff_Settings]
```